# incomplete type and cannot be defined

Tags: qt, user-interface

I have been struggling with this error for more than two hours:

```
error: aggregate 'Ui::UpdaterProgress updaterProgress' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
```

I have a simple UI screen on Qt. Setting up with a dialog:

```
  #include <ui_UpdaterProgress.h>

  namespace Ui {
  class UpdaterProgress;
  }
  ....
  Ui::UpdaterProgress updaterProgress;
  QDialog updateProgressDialog;
  updaterProgress.setupUi(&updateProgressDialog);
```

It's a simple UI with an icon, two labels, progress bar and a cancel button. Am I doing anything wrong here?

I get this error if I don't do the forward declaration:

```
error: 'UpdaterProgress' is not a member of 'Ui'
error: expected `;' before 'updaterProgress'
error: 'updaterProgress' was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: `ui_UpdaterProgress.h` should have the definition.  What error message do you get if you do not forward declare it yourself?

Comment: If you're `#include`ing ui_UpdaterProgress.h, you shouldn't need the forward declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you defined class UpdaterProgress in your `....`???
Define your `UpdaterProgress` class before using it in `Ui::UpdaterProgress updaterProgress;`.
Prototyping itself cannot tell anything about the class, that's why incomplete type error.

Comment: I had given the default name for the Dialog when I created using the designed. When I gave UpdaterProgress as the dialog, it auto-generated the class for me and it worked.